# Can't figure out unity scene load delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So the problem here is that i'm trying to delay the sceneload and show a win screen for a few seconds, unlock the next level(which works btw) and fade the player into a portal. Instead it just loads the next scene instantly when i enter my portal. Can't seem to figure it out myself.

`public float menuCounter;
public int nextSceneLoad;

```
void Start()
{
   nextSceneLoad = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1;
}

void Update()
{
    menuCounter -= Time.deltaTime;



    if (menuCounter is >= 0.1f and <= 0.2f)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(nextSceneLoad);
    }
    if (menuCounter is >= 1.8f and <= 1.9f)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Sprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.9f);
    }
    if (menuCounter is >= 1.7f and <= 1.8f)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Sprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.8f);
    }
    if (menuCounter is >= 1.6f and <= 1.7f)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Sprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.7f);
    }
    if (menuCounter is >= 1.5f and <= 1.6f)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Sprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.6f);
    }
    if (menuCounter is >= 1.4f and <= 1.5f)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Sprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f);
    }
    if (menuCounter is >= 1.3f and <= 1.4f)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Sprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.4f);
    }
    if (menuCounter is >= 1.2f and <= 1.3f)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Sprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.3f);
    }
    if (menuCounter is >= 1.1f and <= 1.2f)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Sprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.2f);
    }
    if (menuCounter is >= 1f and <= 1.1f)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Sprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.1f);
    }
    if (menuCounter is >= 0.2f and <= 1f)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Sprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex == 4)
        {
            Debug.Log("You Completed ALL Levels");

            //Show Win Screen or Somethin.
        }
        else
        {
            //Move to next level
            

            //Setting Int for Index
            if (nextSceneLoad > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelAt"))
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("levelAt", nextSceneLoad);
            }
            menuCounter = 2f;
            GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Movement>().enabled = false;
            GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().bodyType =  RigidbodyType2D.Static;
            GameObject.Find("StageClear").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().enabled = true;
            GameObject.Find("StageClearSound").GetComponent<AudioSource>().enabled = true;
            GameObject.Find("MusicControl").GetComponent<AudioSource>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}
`

I've tried adding a coroutine and Invoke with a delay but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I would recommend you not to spam both GameObject.Find() and GetComponent<>() methods like that, simply cached only once your references for both the gameobject "Sprite" and component "SpriteRenderer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely use a routine instead of `Update` for this.

Main reason: The `Update` runs all the time. So it is pretty much possible that you run through all of the conditions before you collide since `menuCounter` will with or without collision eventually reach `<= 0.2f` => directly jumps into

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(nextSceneLoad);
```

Another reason: With your setup yo might easily skip a condition and maintenance will be really bad if you want to adjust the times or add/remove steps ;)

I would probably rather do something like this

```
int currentScene;
int nextSceneLoad;

void Start()
{
   currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
   nextSceneLoad = currentScene + 1;
}

private bool isAlreadyLoading;

// "OnTriggerEnter2D" can return IEnumerator in which case
// Unity will automatically tread and run it as a coroutine
IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    // if already loading ignore
    if(isAlreadyLoading) yield break;

    // if not player ignore
    if (!other.CompareTag("Player")) yield break;
    
    if (currentScene == 4)
    {
        Debug.Log("You Completed ALL Levels");

        //Show Win Screen or something
    }
    else
    {
        if (nextSceneLoad > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelAt"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("levelAt", nextSceneLoad);
            // I would also save this
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
        }
           
        // In general "Find" is very expensive!
        // you already seem to have a reference to the player since it collided with you!
        other.GetComponent<Movement>().enabled = false;
        other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().bodyType =  RigidbodyType2D.Static;
        GameObject.Find("StageClear").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().enabled = true;
        GameObject.Find("StageClearSound").GetComponent<AudioSource>().enabled = true;
        GameObject.Find("MusicControl").GetComponent<AudioSource>().enabled = false;

        // set flag to ignore any later collisions
        isAlreadyLoading = true;

        // store these ONCE
        var sprite = GameObject.Find("Sprite").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        var material = sprite.material;

        // if I'm not completely mislead I think you want to fade out your sprite
        // from fully white opaque to fully transparent
        var startColor = Color.white;
        var targetColor = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0f);
        // Coudld be a const or even better adjustable via the Inspector
        float fadeDuration = 2f;

        // Every frame move the timePassed forward and interpolate the sprite color
        for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < fadeDuration; timePassed += Time.deltatime)
        {
            // will be a factor moving 0 -> 1 within fadeDuration
            var factor = timePassed / fadeDuration;
            // interpolate startColor -> targetColor within fadeDuration
            sprite.color = Color.Lerp(statColor, targetColor, factor);
            // "pause" routine here, render this frame and continue from here in next frame
            yield return null;
        }

        sprite.enabled = false;

        // wait an additional second
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        // finally load the scene
        SceneManager.LoadScene(nextSceneLoad);
    }
}
```